# How is the set $S = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} \: |z − 2| \lt 3|z|\}$ simply connected?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

I have sketched the set $ S = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} \: |z − 2| \lt 3|z|\} $ and to me it appears to be the complement set to the closed ball $B(\frac14, \frac34)$. As a result I can think can come up with a polygonal path that has a limit to the amount it can be shrunk and still be within $S$.

But to my surprise, the solution to this question states that $S$ is indeed simply connected, since 'There are no holes'?

I am not sure why?

Comment: What is this question from?

Comment: Textbooks contain mistakes from time to time. Mostly they're just misprints, and sometimes they ar genuine mistakes. Perhaps the inequality was supposed to be the other way? You hardly need to do any computation to see that it is wrong as stated: Clearly, every $z$ with sufficiently large absolute value satisfies the inequality, and some $z$ do not; that's your hole, right there.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen Okay cool, so the answer is incorrect and my reasoning is correct?

Comment: Yup. See my comment above (I was editing it when your comment came in.)

Comment: @ThomasGrubb The question was from a problem sheet from my university.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen Yeah, cool. Thanks for your assistance and assurance regarding this topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inequality is equivalent to $|z-2|^2<9|z|^2$. If $z=x+iy$ this says
$$(x-2)^2+y^2<9x^2+9y^2,$$or $x^2+\frac12x+y^2>\frac12.$Completing the square, this is $$\left(x+\frac12\right)^2+y^2>\frac34.$$That is indeed the complement of a disk, but not the disk you say; it's the complement of $B(-1/2,\sqrt 3/2)$.

So  yes, it's not simply connected.

You should look carefully to see whether your sketch is wrong or I made a mistake in the algebra...

Answer (score 2):

Divide by $z$ to obtain $|1-2/z|< 3$, or equivalently $|1/z-1/2|< 3/2$. This means that $1/z$ is in the circle with radius $3/2$ around $1/2$. Hint: $1/z$ is (geometrically) the composition of the inversion to the unit circle and the reflection to the $x$ axis.